# Migration from Neo4j to Janusgraph

Tags: neo4j, janusgraph

I am currently using the Neo4j Community Edition for my graph needs but since community edition does not support clustering, facing scalability issues. So I am thinking of switching to Janusgraph. Is there any way I can migrate the database from Neo4j to Janusgraph.

Comment: What scalability issues ?

Comment: Hi Christophe, I am currently using Neo4j for recommendation purpose (for which I am also using neo4j-reco graphaware module). The graph has more than 2 million nodes and 20 million relationships. My cypher queries are very time consuming and sometimes takes more than 10 seconds to execute. That's why I thought to parallelise this but community edition does not support clustering. So, thinking of migrating to Janusgraph.

Comment: Did you ever ask for help fixing your queries. 10s sounds like not optimized at all

Comment: Yeah, 12 millions objects is a very very very small graph. Your first problem is definitely not scaling but make your model, queries and code right

Comment: Thanks Michael and Christophe for your comments. I have tried to explain my problem in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804236/neo4j-recommendation-cypher-query-optimization

Can you advice me how to proceed?